# timthumb and apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've just installed a new instance on AWS with Apache 2 and PHP 5.4.  Everything is working except [timthumb.php](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/).  The error I see is:

```
Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/photos/thumb (None could be negotiated).
```

My .htaccess file in /photos looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^thumb/(.*)$ /photos/thumb.php?src=http://cdn.my-host.com/$1 [L]
```

After doing some research it looked like I needed to add the PHP type so I did this in my mime.conf file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

After restarting apache I now see this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/photos/thumb.php'
```

Am I heading down the wrong path? I'm trying to resolve the first error but I think I'm headed in the wrong direction.  Any thoughts what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off mod_negotiation

At the top of your htaccess file, add:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Mod_negotiation sees a request like `/photos/thumb/something`, and when it tries to map that URI to a file, it sees the file at `/photos/thumb.php`, and thinks that the request was for that file (which it is). The problem is that this will completely bypass mod_rewrite, so your rules don't get applied.

Comment: When doing this I now see:  PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/photos/thumb.php'

Comment: @Paul you have proper permissions setup under `/photos/`?

Comment: I believe so... thumb.php has 644

Comment: @Paul There's lots of reason why you could get that error, like if `/photos/` wasn't `755`, or [many other similar reasons](https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+Warning%3A+Unknown%3A+failed+to+open+stream%3A+Permission+denied+in+Unknown+on+line+0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs), but it's not related to htaccess, it's a permissions issue

Comment: ok...you've helped me get rid of this error so I'll look into it.  Thanks again!